# Missing: List of questions with no accepted answer?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, accepted-answer

My user profile includes a list of my asked questions, and I can sort this by recent/views/newest/votes. **One sorting option is missing: *no accepted answer.***

A few of my older questions don't have an accepted answer yet (for various reasons, on various SE sites), thus giving me less than 100% closing rate.

I have asked lots of questions so the question list is several "pages" long. It's cumbersome to leaf through the pages and look for questions that have no accepted answer. Is there a smart way of doing this??

Answer (score 7):

> It's cumbersome to leaf through the pages and look for questions that have no accepted answer. Is there a smart way of doing this?

Searching with `user:me hasaccepted:0` will return questions you've asked but have not accepted any answers

https://superuser.com/search?q=user:me+hasaccepted:0

Adding `closed:0` will skip questions which have been closed

https://superuser.com/search?q=user:me+hasaccepted:0+closed:0

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful hack! Do you mean to imply that there really is no *official* way to do this? (read: no user-friendly hyperlink to click on?)

Comment: @Torbegb I don't think there's an "official" link as such. This was [brought up before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1081/133693) perhaps it's worthwhile bringing it up again